# Creating a derived column using pandas operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a column which contains a cumulative sum of the number of entries, `tid`, which are grouped according to unique values of `(raceid, tid)`. The cumulative sum should increment by the number of entries in the grouping as shown in the `df3` `dataframe` below rather than one at a time.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'rid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    'tid': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3]})

    rid  tid
0     1    1
1     1    2
2     1    2
3     2    1
4     2    1
5     2    3
6     3    1
7     3    4
8     4    5
9     5    1
10    5    1
11    5    1
12    5    3
```

Giving after the required operation:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'rid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    'tid': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3],
    'groupentries': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1],
    'cumulativeentries': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2]})

    rid  tid  groupentries  cumulativeentries
0     1    1             1                  1
1     1    2             2                  2
2     1    2             2                  2
3     2    1             2                  3
4     2    1             2                  3
5     2    3             1                  1
6     3    1             1                  4
7     3    4             1                  1
8     4    5             1                  1
9     5    1             3                  7
10    5    1             3                  7
11    5    1             3                  7
12    5    3             1                  2
```

The derived column that I'm after is the `cumulativeentries` column although I've only figured out how to generate the intermediate column `groupentries` using `pandas`:

```
df1.groupby(["rid", "tid"]).size()
```

Comment: Could you explain why `cumulativeentries` sometimes drops back to 1? For example, what is the logic in row 5 and 6?

Comment: I'm looking for the cumulative count of unique entries of `tid` so at row five there has only been one entry for `tid=3`, row six there have been four entries for `tid=1`. The kicker is that the cumulative count should immediately increase to the total value including all identical entries in the current grouping.

Comment: You wrote that value of *cumulativeentries* should **increase**
by the **number of entries in each group**.
So how do explain that for *(rid, tid) == (2, 3)* this value
suddenly **decreased**? Your question contains not a single word
about decrease in this column.

Comment: Kindly add logic behid cumaltive_entries in your question

Comment: Then why does row 1 have cumulative count of `2` when its the first occurence of `tid=2`?

Comment: Sorry, I've found it difficult to phrase what I want to achieve. I'd like the cumulative count of each unique level of the `tid` column with the added proviso that it only updates, at each new value of `rid` to the final count for that group.

Comment: Sorry, Erfan. Row 1's value is 2 because row 1 and row 2 both have two identical entries. I want the `cumulativeentries` count to take the same value for both. The same value as the final value if I had used an incremental count. This is what is a bit tricky about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For first column use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html), for second use custom function for test all values of column to last index values, compare with last values and count matched values by `sum`:

```
f = lambda x:  (df1['tid'].iloc[:x.index[-1]+1] == x.iat[-1]).sum()
df1['groupentries'] = df1.groupby(["rid", "tid"])['rid'].transform('size')
df1['cumulativeentries']  = df1.groupby(["rid", "tid"])['tid'].transform(f)
print (df1)
    rid  tid  groupentries  cumulativeentries
0     1    1             1                  1
1     1    2             2                  2
2     1    2             2                  2
3     2    1             2                  3
4     2    1             2                  3
5     2    3             1                  1
6     3    1             1                  4
7     3    4             1                  1
8     4    5             1                  1
9     5    1             3                  7
10    5    1             3                  7
11    5    1             3                  7
12    5    3             1                  2
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I want though. Row 5 is wrong as I need `cumulativeentries` to equal one for this entry as `tid=3` has only appeared at this point.

Comment: @user2699676 - Can you check now?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't achieve the values that I need. This can be seen if I extend the dataframe with some new values.

Comment: @user2699676 - ok, please change data sample for explain it.

Comment: I've added a few extra rows to the original `dataframe` which should indicate more clearly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Values in `cumulativeentries` are actually a kind of **running count**.
The task is to count occurrences of the current *tid* in "source area" of
*tid* column:

- from the beginning of the DataFrame,
- up to (including) the end of the current group.

To compute values of both required values for each group, I defined
the following function:

```
def fn(grp):
    lastRow = grp.iloc[-1]  # last row of the current group
    lastId = lastRow.name   # index of this row
    tids = df1.truncate(after=lastId).tid
    return [grp.index.size, tids[tids == lastRow.tid].size]
```

To get the "source area" mentioned above I used *truncate* function.
In my opinion it is a very intuitive solution, based on the notion of the
"source area".

The function returns a list containing both required values:

- the size of the current group,
- how many *tid*s equal to the current *tid* are in the
  truncated *tid* column.

To apply this function, run:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['rid', 'tid']).apply(fn).apply(pd.Series)\
    .rename(columns={0: 'groupentries', 1: 'cumulativeentries'})
```

Details:

- *apply(fn)* generates a *Series* containing 2-element lists.
- *apply(pd.Series)* converts it to a DataFrame (with default column names).
- *rename* sets the target column names.

And the last thing to do is to join this table to *df1*:

```
df1.join(df2, on=['rid', 'tid'])
```